# How to generate Object with FOR loop?

Tags: python, flask

I'm studying python flask and I'm trying to generate an **dictionaries** dynamically using a **repeating loop for** but I'm unsure how I can do it using **python**, because in **other languages** ​​just insert the loop for before the item to be repeated, but in python's error. Note that my goal has two data returns. would I like to generate these internal results automatically?

**I want to do something like this:**

```
listStocks = db.execute("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id_user = ?", userId)

car_details = [ <-- Start the loop for here

for i in range (len (list)):
    ##-----------------------------------
    ## Repete that code block
    
    brand = listStocks [i] ["brand"]
    model = listStocks [i] ["model"]

        {
            'brand': brand,
            'model': model,
        }

    ##---------------------------------------
    else: <-- if all items listed, render the template below
]

return render_template ('index.html', car = car_details)
```

**When the loop has no more records to insert into the dictionaries, the result would be this:**

```
car_details = [
    {
        'brand': Fiat,
        'model': Model A
    }
    {
        'brand': Volkswagen,
        'model': Model B
    }
    {
        'brand': Tesla,
        'model': Model C
    }
    {
        'brand': Ford,
        'model': Model D
    }
    {
        'brand': Ferrari,
        'model': Model E
    }
    {
        'brand': Lamborghini,
        'model': Model F
    }
    {
        'brand': BMW,
        'model': Model G
    }
]
```

**My real code:**

```
listStocks = DB.execute("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id_user = ?", userId)

for i in range(len(list)):

    brand = listStocks[i]["brand"]
    model = listStocks[i]["model"]

    car_details = [
        {
            'brand': brand,
            'model': model
        }
    ]

return render_template('index.html', car=car_details)
```

Thank You

Comment: Do you mean to do `else: return render_template('index.html', car=car_details)` ? because you can add that after the `for` loop

Comment: I can't see any objects in this code. car_details looks like a list of dictionaries.

Comment: The listStocks is a Query Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are setting `car_details` inside the loop. Regardless of language the result you received would be the result you got. You likely meant:

```py
listStocks = DB.execute("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id_user = ?", userId)

car_details = [] 
for i in range(len(listStocks)):

    brand = listStocks[i]["brand"]
    model = listStocks[i]["model"]

    car_details.append(
        {
            'brand': brand,
            'model': model
        }
    )

return render_template('index.html', car=car_details)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listStocks = DB.execute("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE id_user = ?", userId)
car_details = [ {'brand': item["brand"], 'model': item["model"] } for item in listStocks ]
return render_template('index.html', car=car_details)
```